# Trying to change value of class variable

Tags: c++, qt, class, variables

Program crushing,when i trying to change class variable
for example:

```
class ITask
{
public:
ITask();
void perform(int,int);
private:
int total = 0;
}
__________implementation___________
void ITask::perform(int a,int b)
{
int time=rand()%10;
this->total=time;
}
```

Without string `this->total=time;` program works.

Comment: Problem is somewhere else...

Comment: You have an invalid pointer to an `ITask` and you're calling the function using that.

Comment: Problem not replicable with posted code.  Please post a complete example.

Comment: @molbdnilo Had that been the problem perform wouldn't have been called.

Comment: Please, provide more code. As @molbdnilo said it is almost surely an invalid pointer to generate such a behaviour but, with just as few lines of code as you provided, it's just guessing.

Comment: @ravi sure it would, doesn't look virtual to me. It's undefined behavior, but it works on most implementations http://ideone.com/4aFBAJ

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Error occurs when I call this method `ITask* task; task->perform(a,b);` The rest of the code does not affect the operation of this

Comment: @molbdnilo Which pointer you think I should use?

Comment: @SergeyProskurnya Can you please put that information in the question? It is essential to understand the problem.

Comment: IF the error is at row X ALL the elements used at that row must be provided. As you have confirmed, the error was in the calling code: the code provided in the question was correct whereas the the code in the comment is the one wrong. See the answer down here for full explanation. Useful considerations about [stack and heap](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/difference-between-stack-and-heap/)

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you use `ITask* task; task->perform(a,b);`. However, `ITask* task;` only declares a pointer to an ITask, it does not create an instance. So your `perform` member function tries to write to a memory location where it thinks `total` resides, but in fact the memory is not allocated for that purpose. Hence the crashing which depends on the presence of the line `this->total=time;`. Note however that the fact that it works without that line is purely implementation defined, as it is still undefined behavior to call a non-static member function without an instance, i.e. without a valid `this` pointer.

Either use

```
 ITask task;
 task.perform(a,b);
```

(to create an `ITask` local to the function) or

```
ITask* task = new ITask();
task->perform(a,b);
//later deallocate:
delete task;
```

(to create an `ITask` that lives until you call the `delete`). Both create actual objects.